# Phase retrieval via SDP (semidefinite program) of 2D test image (Matrix completion)

Tags: convex-analysis, matlab, semidefinite-programming, inverse-problems, matrix-completion

In SDP based phase retrieval we have intensity measurement (abs(FFT2(x))^2) 
of the form

A(xo) = |ak,x|^2 =b^2, phase retrieval is then

find x that obeys A(xo)=b

The quadratic measurements can be lifted and interpreted as linear about rank 1 matrix X =xx*

|ak,x|^2 = b^2 = Tr(AX), with X =xx* and we want to recover the phase (x - signal to recover).

In the standard approach named as phase lift we imagine lift of dimension X =xx*
and we look to minimize rank of Tr(X), subject to A(X)=b, X>=0

And we need roughly 4n measurement for n length signal if I understand it correctly.

This is fine for 1D problems. When we have 2D pahse retrieval going to 4D in X doesnt look good approach.What is the trick for phase recover in the case of 2D phase retrieval problems?

Just few reference links.

I would like to ask how to construct phase retrieval of test picture 2D, let say phantom (phantom('Modified Shepp-Logan',50) in matlab) with semidefinite programing like phaselift.

http://web.stanford.edu/~mahdisol/PhaseRetrieval_CDP.pdf Phase lift method

Examples in 1D online.

http://web.stanford.edu/~mahdisol/PhaseRetrieval_CDP.html

via semidefinite method like phaselift

http://web.stanford.edu/~mahdisol/PRcode.html code

or
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.6323v3.pdf

http://users.isy.liu.se/en/rt/ohlsson/code.html code

Thank you.

Comment: Most of these links are broken.

Comment: yes they are but cant fix them